# Youtube Embed Does Not Work Even If I copied The Correct Embed Code

Tags: html

I have an  tag in my code and I copied the whole code from a youtube source and I was wondering why my iframe won't read the code and won't display my video

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eMobfjIsOfk" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Load it via `https`

Comment: The iframe is working. There might be something else causing the problem.

Comment: I loaded it via https but it still wont work @aMJay

Comment: @AlexDeneris [It works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/7t30bszd/). Without more information from your end, we wont be able to help you. Try to add a [mcve] to your post.

Comment: When I inspect the element from the console, the #document below the iframe does not have a content @Ivar

Comment: @AlexDeneris Are there any errors in your console tab? What is happening in your network tab with calls to YouTube? Do they load properly?

Comment: there are no available errors and I don't see one too @Ivar

Answer (score 0):

You should be loading it via https

Working example - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hunzpf7o/)

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eMobfjIsOfk" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: It is actually loading via https, even if you use http (it will be redirected internally). You just can't connect to http from a https site. If you use jsfiddle without SSL/TLS it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7t30bszd/